# How to improve this LINQ query to find users will all skills in list

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, view

I'm having some trouble optimizing this query.

This is to filter out users that have a particular set of skills.

These skills are sent to the server in the form of a list of their IDs, which are GUIDs.

unfortunately I cannot just get the user as easily as I would like because the last person working on this placed this in a SQL view.

This is where we try and find all users with all skills selected.

`skillIDs` is the list of GUIDs

Here is what it looks like

```
myview.Where(view => skillIDs.All(skill => view.User.Skills.Any(s => s.ID == skill)))
```

Other things we have tried

```
myView.Where(view => !skillIDs.Except(view.User.Skills.Select(skill => skill.ID).Any()))

myview.Where(view => skillIDs.All(skill => view.User.Skills.Select(s => s.ID).contains(skill)))
```

I realize the way it is working is highly inefficient and yes, we are paginating the results, but not until after this query. What I believe is happening is it is executing the query here rather than waiting for the `.skip(0).Take(10).tolist()` which is when it should execute. Right now it takes 45 seconds for this to work.When it's not trying to execute the query above it's less than a second so I know this is the culprit.

Comment: Do you have index's on your columns?

Comment: I do, but you can't really do an index on the sql view

Comment: Why can't you have an index on the view?

Comment: But your trying to get all user who have a set of skills right?

Comment: How many elements does `skillIDs` typically contain?

Comment: yes, but in a particular view. I'm really thinking of scrapping this view because it's honestly been a huge problem

Comment: Yeah what are your metrics

Comment: skillIDs right now that is just testing with only two skillIDs

Answer (score 1):

In this case playing with different variations of LINQ won't make a difference as the issue is likely in the backend table indexing, not in how you create a LINQ statement. You really have two options:

1. Index the backend table as the view will be able to use index on the table if it needs
2. Index a view directly. The definition of an indexed view must be deterministic. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

   CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1
       ON myview (skillid);
   GO

Comment: The problem with that is skillID doesn't exist in the view and has to be grabbed through navigation items so it's not exactly something that can be indexed

Comment: SkillID is indexed in the skills table though

Comment: I suspected it based on your LINQ query; in this case you still have option #1 which is creating an index. It is hard to say exactly where it needs to be without having DB schema. I'd guess maybe on `[Skills]` table?

Comment: So you probably have `skills`, `userSkills` and `User` table, correct? You not only have to index `skills`, but more specifically make sure that your index covers `userSkills`

Comment: Ah shows one on the userID, but not on the skillID. Let me try that

Comment: That's the best I can do without knowing DB schema.